# Bound View over View For particular area in Android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am working on pic collage module in one of my app. [I want to create this type of view for my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaDrg.png). In my app I want to combine all photos in one frame. We have our own defined frames which has different number of images .[Sample for all frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ovb4.png)

I have taken one frameLayout and inside frameLayout I have added view over view programmatically and for border I have used canvas.

[I got this type of view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j445a.png) my view 4 is overLay over other view so i want to restrict this view 4 in limit so can anyone tell me how can i get this?

[I need this type of view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2NdP.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to View appear Diagonally ?

Comment: @ADM like pic collage app. actually i'm developing pic collage module in my app so i need this layout for combining all selected photos do you have any reference ?

Comment: For reference you can see [This](https://github.com/florent37/DiagonalLayout).

Comment: @ADM i've multiple frame so i have to use proper class which solve this issue programmatically

Comment: The question is too broad and somehow unclear too . So edit your question with proper details and your code effort .

Comment: @ADM have you seen any pic collage app?

Comment: @ADM i have added third image for more clarification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166380/discussion-between-ravi-dadhania-and-adm).